# Convert png files to txt files

Tags: r, pdf

I have 100 scanned PDF files and I need to convert them into text files.

I have first converted them into png files (see script below),
now I need help to convert these 100 png files to 100 text files.

```
library(pdftools)
library("tesseract")

#location
dest <- "P:\\TEST\\images to text"

#making loop for all files
myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)

#Convert files to png
sapply(myfiles, function(x)
  pdf_convert(x, format = "png", pages = NULL, 
              filenames = NULL, dpi = 600, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE))

#read files
cat(text)
```

I expect to have a text file for each png file:

> From: file1.png, file2.png, file3.png...
>
> To: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt...

But the actual result is one text file containing all png files text.

Comment: There are several issues with your code. Your `list.files` pattern doesn’t list PDF files but all files with the string `'pdf'` in its name. The comment above that line of code is completely wrong, it doesn’t at all explain what the line is doing. You also didn’t show us the crucial bit — namely, how you are actually trying to OCR the files, and what fails. Instead, the code you’ve shown is, effectively, irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you left out the bit with teh `png -> text` bit, but I assume you used `library(tesseract)`.

You could do the following in your code:

```
library(tesseract)
eng <- tesseract("eng")
sapply(myfiles, function(x) {
  png_file <- gsub("\\.pdf", ".png", x)
  txt_file <- gsub("\\.pdf", ".txt", x)
  pdf_convert(x, format = "png", pages = 1, 
              filenames = png_file, dpi = 600, verbose = TRUE)

  text <- ocr(png_file, engine = eng)
  cat(text, file = txt_file)
  ## just return the text string for convenience
  ## we are anyways more interested in the side effects
  text
})
```